# Adding a column (first column) to csv file with service names and the status

Tags: csv, awk

I am using below code to redirect service names and status on my centos box to a csv file:- 
    service --status-all |
    grep -E running\|stopped |
    awk '{print $1,","," ",$NF,","," "}' >> "$HOME/MyLog/running_services_$HOSTNAME.csv"

Output for service --status-all command on my box is like:-
httpd is running

Now, I basically need the first column in this csv file as the ip address of the centos box. I can get the IP using this:-
ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p'

Output of above command is:- 192.168.0.38 (IP address of my host).

Current CSV Output is like:- ServiceName Status
I would need the output to be as:- IP Address ServiceName Status

I need to know how can I insert the first column in this CSV which will have the IP address for each of the rows - populated with service names and status. Any pointers on this?
Can I print this command output as first column using awk?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but edit your question to show some sample output of both `ifconfig` and `service --status-all` as you don't need those grep and sed commands but we need to see what the input for the awk script would be. Also post the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the IP address first, and give the value to awk

```
ip=$( ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.inet (addr:)?(([0-9].){3}[0-9])./\2/p' )
service --status-all | awk -v ip="$ip" -v OFS="," '/running|stopped/ {print ip, $1, $NF}' >> "$HOME/MyLog/running_services_$HOSTNAME.csv"
```

Note that you don't need grep: awk can do that job.

Comment: @vipinbatra, start with https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html -- if you have a specifid ed question, ask a question about it.